# In pyspark LogisticRegression output, whick probability belongs to which class?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, logistic-regression

My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol="label")
lrm = lr.fit(transformed)
predictions = lrm.transform(transformed)
predictions.select('probability')
```

This gives me 2 probabilities as I have 2 classes.
But I don't know which probability belongs to which class. How to find that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

spark predicts a class based on p>0.5. So select probability and prediction column from the prediction dataframe. Examine the first row of the dataframe, and see which element has the value higher than 0.5 and see the prediction class. So for example element 1 has value of 0.56 and prediction of class 2. Then 0th element of the probability belongs to class 1 probability and 1st element is class 2.

Comment: In my output ,  for all the records/rows, the 1st element of  probability is always higher than 0th element irrespective of predicted class. Does that mean 1st element is always the probability of predicted class?